# Kompose up: Unable to retrieve .docker/config.json

Tags: docker-compose, minikube, kompose

I am converting a simple docker-compose file on my Mac with kompose. But every time I run kompose up I get :

```
WARN Unable to retrieve .docker/config.json authentication details. Check that 'docker login' works successfully on the command line.: Failed to read authentication from dockercfg 
INFO Authentication credentials are not detected. Will try push without authentication. 
INFO Attempting authentication credentials 'docker.io 
ERRO Unable to push image 'bolbeck/simplepythonimage:latest' to registry 'docker.io'. Error: denied: requested access to the resource is denied 
FATA Error while deploying application: k.Transform failed: Unable to push Docker image for service firstpythonhw: unable to push docker image(s). Check that `docker login` works successfully on the command line
```

kompose convert works fine, since it does not try to pull the image. Also `docker login` works just fine from the terminal and I can push images manually.

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  firstpythonhw:
    build: .
    image: MyAccount/pythonimage
    container_name: pythonhw
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

I am using Kompose version 1.18.0 and Minikube version 1.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Kompose](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md#build-and-push-docker-images) documentation, during [Push](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/blob/master/pkg/utils/docker/push.go#L57) image action, Docker authentication data is actually retrieved from docker config file in the following folder check sequence:

```
$DOCKER_CONFIG/config.json, $HOME/.docker/config.json , $HOME/.dockercfg
```

In fact, when you log to the registry via `docker login`, the command saves credentials in `config.json` file. However, Docker also offers a way how to externally store user authentication data via *[Credential stores](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/#credentials-store)* as a main storage for even OS wide key-chains. But this time `Kompose` will not recognize Docker configuration file and entire content structure.

In Mac you can find [*macOS keychain*](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/keychain-access/kyca1083/mac), since you've checked `docker login` I suppose that base64 encoded credentials were not stored in `config.json` file, they just being exported to *“osxkeychain”* on the particular macOS.

**Update:**

Typical `config.json` file structure:

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "base64 encoded username:password"
                }
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.09.7 (linux)"
        }
}
```

Comment: I just checked $HOME/.docker/config.json and the base64 credential are not there. this is all there is for auth: "auths": { "index.docker.io/v1": {} }. So is there a way to make Kompose look at the keychain or force the credentials to be pushed to the config file? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I guess you can supply `"auth"` value manually, encoding docker credentials to base64:`echo "username:password"|base64`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command to generate base64 string on your machine

```
echo -n 'username:password'  | base64
```

Take output of this

and add to the docker compose file

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "your base 64 string"
                }
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.09.7 (linux)"
        }
}
```